# Как на Си получить контент страницы сайта?

Tags: html, c

Почитал разные источники. Типа есть CURL библиотека, она это может. Но она огромная, куча не нужных мне функций. Большая часть из примеров не работает, выводит ошибку типов и т.д. из библиотек.
Мне нужно всего лишь получить HTML текст странички, для дальнейшего парсинга.
Пишут что можно с помощью winsock2 получить что угодно :) Но примеры тоже не работают :(
Разрабатываю в CodeBlocks с компилятором MinGWx64/gcc под Windows 10 64.

Может кто уже делал подобное?

Ссылки и примеры приветствуются (РАБОЧИЕ без танцев с бубном). Я недавно занялся Си, перешел с другого ЯП.

Спасибо заранее за ответы ;)

Comment: Последуй знаку на аватарке и используй curl.

Comment: Ну накрайняк  буст https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/beast/example/http/client/sync-ssl/http_client_sync_ssl.cpp

Comment: Я описал, почему CURL не подходит ;)

Comment: Но другие либы ещё больше по функционалу.

Comment: BOOST для Си++. И 200Мб. уже отпугивает :) Я уже думаю написать на Delphi, он это может. Запускать с параметром адреса странички и сохранять в файл. И на Си потом его парсить. Но это по моему "моя аватарка" получится ;)

Comment: Если curl и winsock2 у всех работают, а у вас не работают, значит проблема где-то у вас

Comment: Ну я нахожу статью, с использованием winsock2. Копирую текст, вставляю. Нажимаю компилить, получаю ошибки из библиотек, которые использует winsock2 :) Или в разделе #include подключаются библиотеки, которых нет в поставке в MinGW.

Comment: А сам курл в инклуд прописали?

Comment: *"Копирую текст, вставляю."* - А надо было понять, как оно работает и написать свою программу самостоятельно.

Comment: @user7860670 Нынче это не модно :) https://habr.com/ru/articles/521104/ Или GPT заставить писать код и удивляться, почему оно не заработало...

Comment: @eri В примерах по CURL пишут #include <curl/curl.h> и типа работает. Но видимо нужно еще много чего сделать. На сайте CURL много сказано как на Linux это делать, а про Windows скудно написано.

Comment: @user7860670 Я придерживаюсь правила, разбираться в том что как минимум запускается. И естественно в том коде, который работает и запускается, можно что-то понять. Я написал что я в Си не профи. И если выскакивает ошибка из библиотеки, которую использует сам CURL к примеру, то перейдя в Си из Делфи мне кажется что это ошибка самой CURL! Ибо в Делфи, если есть библиотека (юнит) то она без ошибок должна компилироваться.

Comment: @FrancNet, а может попробовать перейти в linux, раз там примеры работают?

Comment: @avp Хорошая идея? :) Но хотелось бы реализовать это под Windows. В Linux реализация API другая, и сама среда. И естественно то что я задумал в конечном итоге, должно работать (к сожалению) в самой распространенной ОС. Только этим ограничено.
Хотя Windows 11 уже умеет, или есть в ближайших планах, запуск Андроид приложений под Windows 11+. И если бы формат ELF выполнялся на ОС Windows как обычный PE формат, я бы разрабатывал в Linux под Windows ;)

Comment: @FrancNet, может пора уже сделать винду не самой распространенной ОС?

Comment: @avp Ну не всем хочется что-то вводить руками, аля DOS 80x ;) Проще мышкой 2 раза :) А там всякие SUDO =))) Пока как в iOS не сделают менеджер установки пакетов с GUI, удачи не видать... Ну или 2 варианта установки, "аля" Windows и "аля" SUDO =) Не все хотят помнить еще кучу команд, вводить их в терминале. Вот винда и подкупает своей простатой =)

Comment: Да уж, каждому свое

Comment: Там есть гуи для пакетов, вот только платных приложений мало

Comment: @eri Ну не знаю, стоит у меня Ubuntu на виртуалке и никаких GUI там нет :(
Я ради интереса скачал установочный пакет DrWeb и никак не смог его поставить, не ПКМ. Только sudo.

Answer (score 0):

> Я недавно занялся Си, перешел с другого ЯП.

Совет таков, что если вы только начали знакомиться с данным языком, то вам стоило бы сначала изучить его основы, работу со строками, как выводить текст на экран, и т.д.

В данный момент, предлагать в ответах то что вы хотите, не разумно по несколькис причинам, одна из них, это то, что у вас не указан компилятор которым вы пользуетесь, не указана ОС.

Средствами самого языка, этого сделать нельзя, здесь необходимо использовать средства которые предлагают платформа и ОС на которой вы работаете, а также некоторые библиотеки, например curl.

Есть 2 варианта получения контента страницы:

1. Запустить curl с параметрами вывода контента в терминал, и считать его через pipe.
2. Написать и подключить библиотеку curl.

В любом случае, это не то что необходимо делать начиная знакомство с языком.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif /* __cplusplus */

#include <curl/curl.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif /* __cplusplus */

#define REQUEST_URL ("https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_URL.html")

/* https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html */
struct memory {
  char *response;
  size_t size;
};

static size_t cb(void *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *clientp) {
  size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
  struct memory *mem = (struct memory *)clientp;

  char *ptr = realloc(mem->response, mem->size + realsize + 1);
  if(ptr == NULL)
    return 0;  /* out of memory! */

  mem->response = ptr;
  memcpy(&(mem->response[mem->size]), data, realsize);
  mem->size += realsize;
  mem->response[mem->size] = 0;

  return realsize;
}

void
abort_on_error_check(CURLcode code, void(*callback)(void *), void *opaque) {
  if (CURLE_OK != code) {
    fprintf(stderr, "CURL Error: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(code));
    callback(opaque);
    exit(code);
  }
}

#define abort_on_error(code) \
abort_on_error_check(code, curl_easy_cleanup, p_curl)

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  CURL *p_curl;

  struct memory mem = { 0 };

  p_curl = curl_easy_init();
  if (NULL == p_curl) {
    (void) fprintf(stderr, "CURL init failed\n");
  }

  abort_on_error(curl_easy_setopt(p_curl, CURLOPT_URL, REQUEST_URL));
  abort_on_error(curl_easy_setopt(p_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &mem));
  abort_on_error(curl_easy_setopt(p_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, cb));
  abort_on_error(curl_easy_perform(p_curl));

  fprintf(stdout, mem.response);

  free(mem.response);
  curl_easy_cleanup(p_curl);
}
```

```bash
gcc main.c -lcurl -o test.exe
```

> output:

```
evo@evo-pc UCRT64 /d/evo-i/so
$ ./a.exe 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head> <title>CURLOPT_URL</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/curl.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" href="/logo/curl-symbol.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="cURL Releases" href="https://github.com/curl/curl/releases.atom">
<link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="https://curl.se/manpage.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
<div class="menu">
<a href="/libcurl/c/libcurl.html" class="menuitem" title="Overview">API Overview</a>
<div class="dropdown">

....
....
....
```

Comment: Разрабатываю под Windows. GCC (MinGW). Опыт есть, но в Delphi. Всё едино, но есть нюансы ;)
CURL. Я её скачал, описания что нужно что-то компилировать (вроде) нет. В Codeblocks проект, вставляю код из примера работы с CURL. Выходят ошибки компиляции, 
 не понимает заголовки функций из библиотеки CURL. В тексте только #include <curl\curl.h>. Эта и другие библиотеки и заголовки скопированы в GCC в include и lib.
Как я понял нужно в Codeblocks в линковщике указать какие библиотеки нужно добавить к проекту. Я видел пишут #pragma comment(....) для включения откомпилированных библиотек в проект.

Comment: Линковщику нудно указать библиотеку `-lcurl`

Comment: С работой стандартных библиотек проблем нет =) А CURL это большой проект, и вот с его подключением есть проблемы.

Comment: Нет, вы просто не стали ничего о компиляторе, и порядке сборки.

Comment: Да, порядок сборки и компиляции я еще не понимаю полностью.

Comment: В Delphi указал в Uses нужную библиотеку и вперёд =)

Comment: Я буду за компом и попробую указать линковщику -lcurl Если возникнут проблемы, напишу. Спасибо за советы ;)

Comment: Всеравно ошибка. Не понимает заголовки функций библиотеки. undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_init'|

Comment: При использовании winsock2 были такие же ошибки, включив #pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib") всё скомпилировалось. Но через winsock2 у меня не выходит GET запрос =))) 301 Redirect...

Comment: Добавил в Linker две библиотеки libcurl.a и libcurl.dll.a . запустилось, но пишет что теперь нет libcurl-x64.dll :) танец с бубнами продолжается...

Comment: В общем еще кучу DLL требует. Я накидал под Delphi консольное приложение, оно тоже с одной DLL. Запускаю с параметром "url addr" и получаю в файле код страницы.
А CURL может и круче, но очень большой. И для получения только контента для парсинга, слишком велик. Ну и сложен :)

Comment: спасибо за пример. Но CURL оказалась большой, там только одна длл 6 метров весит. А их там нужно кучу.
Я на сокетах пробую, но слишком всё там низкоуровнево ;)
Много примеров где чаты делают. А вот сформировать GET запрос и на редиректы перейти, не так еще просто для меня :)
Но сокеты дают еще больше фантазии, для реализации проектов с сетью.

Comment: Кстати в первом посте, была указана ОС, компилятор и среда разработки ;)

Comment: Да уже не важно, есть ещё библиотека `nng`, раз уж хотите без каких либо зависимосте, собирайте статическую библиотеку и вперёд. https://github.com/nanomsg/nng

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю. А то сокеты слишком низкоуровневы :) Нужно еще изучать как сервер принимает GET запросы, как на переадресацию реагировать. Но это тоже интересно ;)

Comment: EVO а у тебя случайно нет способа в консоле, отследить курсорные клавиши?
Там получается при getch() получаем первый код 224, а вторым считыванием 75 для стрелки в лево.
Но ASCII 224 совпадает с буквой "р" . И если в логике читать следующий символ то букву "р" нет возможности ввести с первого раза.
Я написал функцию ввода, редактирования, строки. Но перемещение право лево не получается.
Хотя какая-то стандартная функция это делает. Но ей не как не передать строку для редактирования.
Я читал, есть вариант с getchar() с отключением ECHO вывода буфера. Но может это как-то проще делается?

Comment: Это не относится к текущему вопросу

Comment: evo ты серьезно? За лайки отвечаешь? а так нет смысла? =)

Comment: Прочитай правила сайта пожалуйста, поймёшь зачем здесь вопросы, это не форум https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Ну по сути вопрос - ответ. Никто ничего не нарушает :) Вопрос по Си? по Си!
Просто программа, которую я пишу, не только получает HTML текст, а далее с ним делает некие манипуляции на Си. И это вопрос не из другой сферы, а по ходу вопроса :)
Т.к. ты больше всех участников разбираешься в Си, то и вопрос именно тебе :)

Нет ну если так, то я могу создать вопрос, изложенный выше, специально для тебя :)
Какой вариант лучше?

Comment: Новый вопрос необходимо создавать, т к. Мало ли кто из сети будет смотреть

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, тут нужно только сокеты и немного знания протокола http. И просто послать запрос. Вот как можно поиграть:

```
(venv) pooh@dell ~ $ telnet httpbin.org 80
Trying 3.234.71.36...
Connected to httpbin.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /ip HTTP/1.1
Host: httpbin.org

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 21 Nov 2023 17:35:08 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 33
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

{
  "origin": "46.123.245.170"
}
```

Все, что после пустой строки, уже прислал сервер. Так что если простые запросы, то курл можно не тащить. Однако, если https, то все несколько сложнее…

Comment: А при чём тут Си?

Comment: Дык это метод, подсказка, не больше. А как это реализовать на Си, уж это к автору вопроса, если захочет:)

Comment: @aikipooh Я пробовал на сокетах. К примеру маил.ру делает 301 редирект, я из ответа получаю строку адреса, отправляю ему повторно, он опять 301 редирект :)
Потом из статьи понимаю что 80 порт и https это разные фишки, у https порт 443(вроде). Ну там тоже 301 редиректы и т.п.
Но мне понравилось, что это без всяких дополнительных средств работает.
Я в общем это дело параллельно изучаю :) Т.к. конкретных примеров нет. Все аля чаты делают на сокетах :)

Comment: Думаю, первый редирект еще устанавливает печеньки, так что их надо передавать. И вот когда накопится критическая масса того, что придется реализовать, самое время подумать про уже готовый curl:) Кстати, можно curl, который утилита командной строки, запускать в подпроцессе, вместо той написанной утилиты на Delphi.

Comment: Кстати, у меня (на питоне) тоже иногда запускается curl в подпроцессе, потому что так проще, чем патчить установление TLS-соединения в стандартном питоне. Те люди, что поставили -4 твоему ответу, они просто пороха не нюхали :)))

Comment: @aikipooh Ну с ответом и программой на Delphi пришлось воспользоваться для продолжения писать проект :) Если появится решение на Си, то будет хорошо. WINSOCK2 мне понравилась, но если нужно для каждого сайта "колдовать" с запросами то это жесть. В роликах по HTTP, HTTPS пишут что это просто, просто отправляете GET index.html HTTP/1.1 и вуаля, вам пришлют страницу ))) наивные ;) Но поняв как работает WINSOCK2 можно и другие проекты создавать, с работой по сети, что будет +в карму ;)
А CURL это как "чтобы написать и распечатать текст, поставьте Windows" ;))))

Comment: Я поскольку не знаю ничего о требованиях. только общее что-то могу сказать. Сам уже лет 10 на си ничего не пишу, щас только питон. Так что у меня вопросов, что что-то толстое и в крынку не влазит, щас нет:) Впрочем, я и на встройке местами питон использовал, чай не восьмидесятые и не 16 килобайт памяти. Но для общего развития, конечно, разобраться с winsock и внутренностями http — это плюс в карму, тут не поспорить.

Answer (score -4):

В итоге поиска и рабочих вариантов не найдено.
CURL слишком большой для моих задач и сложен в реализации.
Написал на Delphi консольную программку, которая в параметре принимает https адрес и записывает в файл контент. Ну а из Си я это могу парсить и искать то что мне нужно, и сразу в ASCII кодировке.

Всем спасибо.

Comment: Отменил ответ. Т.к. думал что Ваш интерес к этой теме очень низок. А тут до сих пор приходят с идеями ;)